# Getting keyframe info from FLV

Tags: video, flv, keyframe

I'd like to see the amount, and if possible, the exact position of all keyframes within a .FLV movie file. Anyone know of a way to programmatically do this, or at least know a video player that can show the keyframe information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

download the **RichFLV**  from 
[link text](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.home&marketplaceid=1)

from Most Popular tab

Comment: Yeah it works. Later I found out that if you run a Red5 streaming server, and put a movie in a streaming app's streaming folder, there is a meta-data file generated - which really is an XML file showing all the keyframes.